# How properly play an audio file to SKYPE4COM

Tags: c#, naudio, skype4com

I'm developing the skype plugin. It should play an audio file during the call.

Audio player use naudio library

```
public class AudioPlayback : IDisposable, IPlayer
{
    WaveStream _outStream;
    IWavePlayer _player;
    IWaveIn _recorder;
    public event Action<byte[], int> DataAvailable;

    public AudioPlayback()
    {
        _recorder = new WaveInEvent();
        _recorder.WaveFormat = new WaveFormat(16000, 16, 1);
        _recorder.DataAvailable += OnRecorderDataAvailable;
    }
    private void OnRecorderDataAvailable(object sender, WaveInEventArgs e)
    {
        if (DataAvailable!= null)
        {
            DataAvailable(e.Buffer, e.BytesRecorded);
        }
    }
    public void LoadFile(string fileName)
    {
        _outStream = new Mp3FileReader(fileName);
        if (_outStream.WaveFormat.Encoding != WaveFormatEncoding.Pcm)
        {
            _outStream = WaveFormatConversionStream.CreatePcmStream(_outStream);
        }
    }
    private void CreatePlayer()
    {
        if (_player == null)
        {
            var waveOut = new WaveOut();
            waveOut.DesiredLatency = 200;
            waveOut.NumberOfBuffers = 2;
            waveOut.DeviceNumber = 0;
            _player = waveOut;
        }
    }
    public void Play()
    {
        CreatePlayer();
        if (_player.PlaybackState != PlaybackState.Playing)
        {
            if (_player.PlaybackState == PlaybackState.Stopped)
                _recorder.StartRecording();

            _player.Init(_outStream);
            _player.Play();
         }
    }
}
```

In skype plugin class I create NetworkStream and TcpListener. Use event from player to get buffer data and write to the network stream
WriteToStream(buffer, 0, num);
On call started I change input for skype

```
        call.InputDevice[TCallIoDeviceType.callIoDeviceTypeSoundcard] = "";
        call.InputDevice[TCallIoDeviceType.callIoDeviceTypePort] = _inputPort.ToString();
```

Was fighting with this for several hours. Finally got the sound on the another skype only when turn on Stereo Mixer (Recording devices).
The question: is this the right way? I don't like a bit to play sound and capture it. But here I have a positive thing - I capture exactly with parameters appropriate for skype.

Comment: This is more of an Opinionated question and or one of past or previous experience doing what you are trying to do.. what's wrong with your existing code if you were able to get it working..?

Comment: It is not working on default system settings. User should turn on mixer. And I'm not sure that I'm using naudio in the right way.